# How to go around "Exceeded maximum execution time" while running a script on a google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I set a script on a page to hide each row that features a 0 value but it takes too long and the error message "Exceeded maximum execution time" appears every time, is there a way to go around this?

```
{
    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
        .getSheetByName('Dashboard');
    s.showRows(1, s.getMaxRows());
  s.getRange('B:B')
        .getValues()
        .forEach(function (r, i) {
            if (r[0] !== '' && r[0].toString()
                .charAt(0) == 0) s.hideRows(i + 1)
    });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Due to the way Apps Script interfaces with Sheets, each call to the update or retrieve data from the sheet (in this case calling `hideRows()`) is going to take some time (a second or more). Trying to do any operation in a loop can easily lead to your script taking too long.

Unfortunately Sheets doesn't provide a convenient method for hiding many separate rows at once.

Instead of hiding the rows, I recommend a model where you have a "raw data" sheet and a separate "display" sheet. Generate an array from the rows you want to be visible from the data sheet, and write them to your display sheet in one shot using `setValues()`.